# Passing ETag as Bash Variable to cURL

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

I'm struggling passing my etag to cURL and getting a successful response. I get the etag with:

```
etag=$(
  curl \
  -SIXGET \
  -u $token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  "$api_url/domain-types/activation_run/collections/pending_changes" | awk '/^ETag:/ { print $2 }'
```

I have verified that this returns the correct etag. However the following cURL request fails:

```
curl -v -L \
  -u $token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "If-Match: $etag" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "{
        \"sites\": [
        \"$site\"
        ]
  }" \
  "$api_url/domain-types/activation_run/actions/activate-changes/invoke"
```

And the problem here is the line `-H "If-Match: $etag`, if I pass the etag as a literal string (enquoted or not), I get a valid response. For reference, `${etag}`, `\"$etag\"`, putting it in a file and calling it with `@etag.txt` and so on doesn't work either.

This is the error response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address> ... </address>
</body></html>
```

The code snippets above are all located in a script.sh file, which is called with `sudo ./script.sh`

I'm working with the REST API from CheckMK.

Edit: Indeed: On `printf "etag <%q>\n" "$etag"` I get `etag <$'"e3asdajldlskj..."\r'>`. Adding to the etag declaration `| tr -d '\r'` and in the cURL request using `$etag` solves the problem.

Comment: Interesting detail: using `-H "If-Match: $(echo $etag)"` works. I have no clue why this could be and only stumpled upon it by trying different random things in desperation.

Comment: You are correct, yes! It has a trailing line break character. Do want to add your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: `\r` is the carriage return, not a newline... It's usually not in `IFS` by default, so word splitting actually shouldn't remove it. E.g. on my Mac and Debian, `var=$(echo $'foo\r\n'); printf "<%q>\n" $(echo $var)` prints `<$'foo\r'>`. Hmm.

Comment: I see... `var=$(echo $'foo\r\n'); printf "<%q>\n" $(echo $var | tr -d '\r')` does however remove the carriage return. I couldn't tell exactly what the semantic difference is in this case, but the latter option returns a valid response...

Comment: Yep. Doesn't matter though, if removing the CR with `tr` fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, it helps to check if there's something invisible in the value you get. Like extra whitespace, or a trailing newline or such.

Here, `etag` was set from a command substitution, which removes trailing newlines, so it shouldn't be that, but in some other cases you might get one.

To check, use e.g. `printf "etag <%q>\n" "$etag"`. The `%q` specifier should work at least in Bash to print the value quoted/escaped so that any whitespace is visible.

Then, remove the extras, depending on what you see you have.

You showed having a trailing carriage return `\r`, and that could be removed within the shell in Bash with:

```
etag=${etag%$'\r'}
```

(I can't see how passing through `$(echo $etag)` would help with a CR, though, unless you have `IFS` explicitly set to contain one.)

More generally, if you know you want e.g. only alphanumerics from the original command, you could pipe the output through `tr` to remove anything except those:

```
etag=$(curl ... | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9')
```

(`-c` for taking the complement of the given set, `-d` for deleting the matching chars.)

Of course that would also remove any whitespace from the middle, etc.

In Bash, you could also do something like

```
[[ $etag =~ [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ]] && etag="$BASH_REMATCH"
```

to find the leftmost string of alphanumerics from the value, and to use that.

Comment: Whether *`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`* matches only alphanumerics depends on the locale. On a typical locale on a GNU system, it matches on hundreds of characters not classified as alphanumeric such as `₨℀℁℃℅℆℉№℠℡™℻⅍㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜` and of course misses thousands of alnums in non-latin scripts.